# Event delegation in Firefox after Ajax

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery

Below is example html, script and php to submit and reload two forms via jquery ajax. In the real application, the same forms will not be reloaded but a series of forms will be loaded after each is submitted.

**In chrome, IE and safari;** clicking submit results in the intended ajax request. The server responds as intended. Results (showing post variables for conformation) and new forms are loaded into the page as intended. Those new forms can then be submitted and all is good.

**In firefox;** everything works as intended until you try to submit the forms that were loaded via ajax. They will not submit. The original forms do work. It is only the ones added via ajax that don't submit.

I am guessing that this is an "event delegation" issue with the way firefox updates the DOM after the ajax.  I have read the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/on/ and other places but I am at a loss...

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! My goal is to get this functional in the latest versions of chrome, IE, safari and firefox.

**html page with script**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example Ajax Form Submit</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="forms">
<div>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ui-widget">
<form>
<tr>
    <td width="100"></td><td width="300"></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""colspan="3"><h1>Form 1</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Input 1A</td><td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="1A"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="1B" value="Form 1 was submitted" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><button type="submit" >Click Me!</button><input type="submit" value="Submit Form 1" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ui-widget">
<form>
<tr>
    <td width="100"></td><td width="300"></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""colspan="3"><h1>Form 2</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Input 2A</td><td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="2A"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="2B" value="Form 2 was submitted" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form 2" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#forms").on("submit", "form", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "testAjax.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: $(this).serializeArray(),
    success: function(jsonData) {
        htmlData = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
        $.each(htmlData, function(id, data){
            $("#"+id).html(data);
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $("#results").html("<p>Somthing went wrong!</p>");
    }
});
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**testAjax.php**

```
<?php
$htmlOutput['forms'] = 
'<div>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ui-widget">
<form id="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self" action="_self">
<tr>
    <td width="100"></td><td width="300"></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""colspan="3"><h1>Form 1</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Input 1A</td><td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="1A"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="1B" value="Form 1 was submitted" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><button type="submit" >Click Me!</button><input type="submit" value="Submit Form 1" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ui-widget">
<form>
<tr>
    <td width="100"></td><td width="300"></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""colspan="3"><h1>Form 2</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Input 2A</td><td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="2A"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="2B" value="Form 2 was submitted" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form 2" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>';
$htmlOutput['results'] =
'<p>Form 1:<br> 1A = ' . $_POST['1A'] . '<br>1B = ' . $_POST['1B'] . '</p>' .
'<p>Form 2:<br> 2A = ' . $_POST['2A'] . '<br>2B = ' . $_POST['2B'] . '</p>';
echo json_encode($htmlOutput);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Firebug DOM inspector and verify that your form indeed loaded. I am pretty sure you are not allowed to nest form element directly under table element, and FF is likely simply dropping it.
In general issues like this one are always due to broken HTML. Verify that your HTML is correct. Verify that loaded DOM is what you expect it to be.

[Here](http://i.imgur.com/OJ6RQ.png) is how your HTML is being parsed. As expected form has been mangled.

Comment: ok. Please keep in mind I am newbee here. In firbug, after the ajax call, under DOM, window, htmlData, forms I see the form html as expected. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes that is what I am suggesting. But I am not seeing your HTML being parsed correctly. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will work on the html and post an update.

Comment: You are correct! If I simply move the form tags outside the table, all is well. I guess I need to get back to the basics of html. Are you aware of any tutorials or the like that would help with using tables (or other methods) to structure forms?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything of sorts. For me it is 80% common sense, 19% verifying things in the Firebug's DOM inspector and 1% googling. There are some not entirely obvious things like for instance `p` tag cannot contain another `p` tag, but again - that's what DOM inspector for.